# Concatenate of ints

Tags: c++

I want to concatenate the ints from an int array and equal them to an int.

e.g

```
int arr[]={1,2,4,0};
int arr2[]= {1,0,2,3};
```

gives me an output of

```
int num = 1240; 
int num2 = 1023;
```

The method I tried was multiplying each index with 10 to a certain power and then added them. (The conversion to decimal method). However, it won't show the '0' in the array. Kindly help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to multiplicate the result by 10 and add the index :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  int   arr[4];

  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 0;
  arr[2] = 2;
  arr[3] = 3;

  int i = 0;
  int res = 0;

  while (i < 4) {
      res = res * 10 + arr[i];
      ++i;
  }
  std::cout << res << std::endl; // print 1023
}
```

Comment: Why get rid of the array intialization, requiring explicit size? Why create the function-scope variable `i`? Why a while loop? Why hardcode the array size in two places?

Comment: He is clearly starting to dev, so i wanted to make it as clear as possible for him to understand

Comment: OP has initialization of the array in the question, why change that to make it worse?

Answer (score 4):

This seems like the time for the handy-dandy [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) which can left-fold over a sequence. All you need to provide are the iterators, your initial value (zero), and a BinaryFunction to do your math:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 4, 0};
int res = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0,
  [](int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs * 10 + rhs; });
```

If you prefer to use a loop, the simplest way would be:

```
int res{};
for (auto i : arr) {
    res = res * 10 + i;
}
```

Or if you can't use C++11 you can index

```
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]); ++i) {
    res = res * 10 + arr[i];
}
```

or use the pointers directly

```
int res = 0;
for (int* p = arr; p != arr + (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]); ++p) {
    res = res * 10 + *p;
}
```